# Jquery image resizing bug in Internet Explorer 8 and 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've designed a website using some Jquery techniques. My problem is that in some random cases, Internet Explorer 8 and 6 can make the images look smaller than they should be. I didn't check with Explorer 7, but it's probably there too... Note that resizing the page might be more liable to cause these problems, and in fact, the client noticed the problem on a 1024x768 resolution monitor.

I'm putting the images in a div, and toggling it with Jquery when a URL is clicked, for the animated effect. It works 100% well in Firefox, but randomly looks weird in Explorer.

How it should look:
[image: How it should look]

What it ends up looking like:
[image: What it ends up looking like]

The Jquery code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#header').supersleight({shim: 'images/x.gif'}); 
            $('div[class^=images]').hide();

            $('a[class=images-importers]').click(function() {
                        $('div[class=images-importers]').toggle(1000);
                        return false;
            });

            $('a[class=images-suppliers]').click(function() {
                $('div[class=images-suppliers]').toggle(1000);
                return false;
            });

        });
</script>
```

The HTML for the relevant section is also below:

```
    <div>
              <p>
                <a href="#" class="images-importers">We are the sole importers of the leading aquatic
                products in Malta.</a>
              </p>
              <div class="images-importers">
                <div class="imgcontainer-small">
                  <a href="..."><img src="..."
                  alt="..." class="glossy" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imgcontainer-small">
                  <a href=".../"><img src="..." alt=
                  "..." class="glossy" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="imgcontainer-small">
                  <a href="..."><img src="..." alt=
                  "..." class="glossy" /></a>
                </div>

                </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS I used for the images :

```
.imgcontainer-small{
    text-align      : left;     
    padding         : 10px;
```

}

Thanks for any help!

Btw, the site is [here](http://users.waldonet.net.mt/aquahobbies/products.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the "Glossy" script I'm using. When I disable it for IE browsers, the bug doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Is there any way you can share the full code? I can't tell what is happening exactly from what you've posted.

Comment: Ok, I added a link to the live site : http://users.waldonet.net.mt/aquahobbies/products.html
I'm still an amateur webdesigner, so go easy on any mistakes I made...or not, point them out as much as you like!

Answer (score 0):

This isnt an issue with jQuery or IE - instead, it is an issue with the PNG processing library you are using (supersleight) which is doing that.

It may actually be the method that supersleight is using to apply transparency to the PNGs in IE.

While they certinaly do work (most of the time), these methods are very bad for performance.  Make sure you absolutely NEED transparent PNGs.  There are often other ways of going about this, including using a separate style sheet for IE browsers that use Gifs or another image format.

Comment: Supersleight is only being applied to the header. But, I'll try and remove it, and see if anything changes.

Comment: I removed it, the same thing happened again.

Comment: Also, sometimes not all the images get resized that small, sometimes some of them do, and some don't..